# Argument error with remove constraint py code

Tags: python, interface

This is the constraint remove function:

```
class DeleteTrackTo(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "delete.trackto"
    bl_label = "Delete TrackTo"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):   

        obj = bpy.context.active_object        
        constraint_to_remove = obj.constraints.get("TRACKTO")

        obj.constraints.remove(constraint_to_remove)

        return{'FINISHED'}
```

This is the Pie menu calling the constraint remove function:

```
class PieManipulateObject(Menu):
    bl_idname = "pie.manipulateobject"
    bl_label = "Object Edit"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene 

        pie = layout.menu_pie()

        col.operator("object.track_set").type='TRACKTO'
        col.operator("delete.trackto")
```

I get this error message when calling the remove function:

> TypeError: ObjectConstraints.remove(): error with argument 1,
>   "constraint" -  Function.constraint does not support a 'None'
>   assignment Constraint type

Comment: it is `obj.constraints.remove()`

Comment: you can always try it in blender python console and you 'll get auto completion this really help  ( also the docs )

Comment: I adjusted the code a little but ran into the following error.

Comment: you have to pass the name of the constraint not the type to the get()  function ( which is returning None because it doesn't find the constraint with a name "TRACKTO"  ), also it would be better to check if the constraint exist before deleting it

Comment: @Chebhou I see. This then renders the problem that in case the Name got changed the script will fail. That is why I thought you could filter out the constraint via the type (trackto) and not via the individual name.

Comment: you can loop through all constraints and if their type is trackto you delete them

Comment: How do you do that? I thought with "obj.constraints.get("TRACKTO")" I would be able to do that.

Comment: `for c in obj.constraints : if c.type=='TRACKTO' : ....`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35757/discussion-between-claas-kuhnen-and-chebhou).